# Multiple two-classes css-selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to understand multiple class selectors in CSS:

That's my starting point:

```
<div class="content-wrapper layout-TILE">
   <div class="content draggable>           /* draggable is added/removed dynamically */
       <img class="some-image-class">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper layout-LIST">
   <div class="content draggable>           /* draggable is added/removed dynamically */
       <img class="some-image-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

`img` size usually depends just on `.content-wrapper` and `.layout-XXX`, for example:

```
.content-wrapper.layout-LIST .some-image-class {
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

.content-wrapper.layout-TILE .some-image-class {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

But when `.draggable` is added to `.content`, how can I formulate a combined selector for two two-classes conditions like this:

```
.content-wrapper.layout-TILE AND .content.draggable .some-image-class {
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
}

.content-wrapper.layout-LIST AND .content.draggable .some-image-class {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can use:

```
.content-wrapper.layout-TILE .draggable .some-image-class {
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
}

.content-wrapper.layout-LIST .draggable .some-image-class {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

This way only when the `.draggable` classname is added will those styles be applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
.content-wrapper.layout-TILE .content.draggable .some-image-class {
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
}

.content-wrapper.layout-LIST .content.draggable .some-image-class {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

(don't forget the dot for the image class and watch the use of spaces)

or, even more specific (for *direct* descendant relations):

```
.content-wrapper.layout-TILE > .content.draggable > .some-image-class {
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
}

.content-wrapper.layout-LIST > .content.draggable > .some-image-class {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @mikerojas was a tad faster :)