# CSS selector, multiple class's to style diferente elements

Tags: css

im trying to reduce lines of css and i cant figure out on how to do it. I have 2 tables and i want to style both with same styles and their's `TD and TH` too.

I have read, [Multiple classes in CSS Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357211/multiple-classes-in-css-selector) , [Multiple two-classes css-selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877500/multiple-two-classes-css-selector) , [css multiple class / id selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458169/css-multiple-class-id-selectors) , [CSS selector for multiple sub-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574031/css-selector-for-multiple-sub-elements)

What i have:

So 2 tables same styles. This is ok, it works.

```
  .documents_table, #documento_detalhe {
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     width: 100%;
  }
```

But now how to select both tables and theirs TDs and THs?

This doenst work:

```
.documents_table, #documento_detalhe td, th {
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px;
   border:0;
 }
```

This is what i have but i want to reduce lines:

```
.documents_table td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border:0;
}

#documento_detalhe td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that by writing
`.documents_table td, th, { styles }` The styles are applied to all `td` inside `.documents_table` and to **ALL** `th` from your html. **Not just the ones in the `.documents_table`** . Your selector should be `.documents_table td, .documents_table th`

Having said that, to style the `td` and `th`s from both tables you should write

```
 .documents_table td, 
.documents_table th, 
#documento_detalhe td, 
#documento_detalhe th { 
...styles 
}
```

BUT, it would be better to add a common class to both tables like '.my-table' and so you would write just `.my-table td, my-table th { styles }` and it would apply to both.

See below

```css
.my-table th, .my-table td {
    color:red;
 }
```

```html
<table id="documento_detalhe" class="my-table">
  <tr><th>TH #documento_detalhe<th></tr>
  <tr><td> TD #documento_detalhe<th></tr>
</table>

<table class="documents_table my-table">
  <tr><th>TH documents_table<th></tr>
  <tr><td> TD documents_table<th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ye i tought about creating a class and apply to all tables, but i got curious on what was the best approach to it. Thanks

Comment: @BRABO if ALL the tables you use should have the same styling. Just use the tag selector `table td, table th` . No need for a common className. Again, be careful that `.my-class td, th` won't style only the `th`'s from table `.my-class` but it will style ALL the `th`s from your page. Good luck !